MudMenuItem does not render __RequestVerificationToken and its value in input
I really MudBlazor but now I want to case that I could not Logout if I use MudMenuItem.
This is my code if i use html and tailwindcss only
<div class="page">
    <main>
    <div>
        <AuthorizeView>
            <NavMenu/>
        </AuthorizeView>
    </div>
    <div class="top-row px-4">
        <AuthorizeView>
            <Authorized>
                <div class="flex items-center md:order-2 space-x-1 md:space-x-0 rtl:space-x-reverse">
                    <NavLink class="flex items-center p-2 text-gray-900 rounded-lg dark:text-white hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 group" href="">
                        <Tooltip Text="My Profile">
                            <span data-tooltip-target="tooltip-my-profile" class="material-icons w-5 h-5 text-gray-500 transition duration-75 dark:text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-900 dark:group-hover:text-white mt-2"
                                  aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 22 21">
                                perm_identity
                            </span>
                        </Tooltip>
                    </NavLink>
                    <button type="button" data-dropdown-toggle="language-dropdown-menu" class="inline-flex items-center font-medium justify-center px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-900 dark:text-white rounded-lg cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white">
                        OL
                    </button>
                    <div class="z-50 hidden my-4 text-base list-none bg-white divide-y divide-gray-100 rounded-lg shadow dark:bg-gray-700" id="language-dropdown-menu">
                        <ul class="py-2 font-medium" role="none">
                            <div class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white" role="menuitem">
                                <div>
                                    <form method="post" action="Account/Logout">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="ReturnUrl" value="@currentUrl"/>
                                        <AntiforgeryToken/>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link p-0 m-0 align-baseline">Logout</button>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Authorized>
        </AuthorizeView>
    </div>
    </main>
</div>

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <div class="p-6 sm:ml-64">
            @Body
        </div>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <div class="p-6">
            @Body
        </div>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>

when i inspect the logout button i can see
<form method="post" action="Account/Logout" b-hd7hv3j7oi=""><input type="hidden" name="ReturnUrl" value="" b-hd7hv3j7oi=""><!--!-->
                                        <!--!--><input type="hidden" name="__RequestVerificationToken" value="CfDJ8G_cBmEwUKhCmRlPfqeZm3ATqgxry1RVVEYYoaQI96r5YUnADlYMBo_Up_k2dhn7B6Q4vh8zQGKWk9L80ybHCwbVLHbsFZ79eBzxn-LS8BnSygq1uKKwIgpWe31S08OXwANA0QPZXgLCUW5blHXd9bTrCB11PEHLdtIus8euqpjocF_q5di_X3Hw68pYwxYeWw"><!--!-->
                                        <!--!--><button type="submit" class="btn btn-link p-0 m-0 align-baseline" b-hd7hv3j7oi="">Logout</button></form>

This is my MainLayout.razor if i use MudBlazor
<MudThemeProvider/>
<MudPopoverProvider/>
<MudDialogProvider/>
<MudSnackbarProvider/>

<MudLayout>
    <MudAppBar Elevation="25">
        <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Menu" Color="Color.Inherit" Edge="Edge.Start" OnClick="@((e) => DrawerToggle())"/>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.h5" Class="ml-3">Leader Cloud Platform</MudText>
        <MudSpacer/>
        <AuthorizeView>
            <Authorized>
                <MudMenu Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Notifications" Color="Color.Inherit" Direction="Direction.Bottom" OffsetY="true">
                    <ActivatorContent>
                        <MudBadge Content="@(_notifications.Count)" Color="Color.Secondary" Overlap="true" Bordered="true">
                            <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Notifications" Color="Color.Inherit"/>
                        </MudBadge>
                    </ActivatorContent>
                    <ChildContent>
                        @if (_notifications.Count == 0)
                        {
                        <MudText Class="px-4 py-2">No new notifications</MudText>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        @foreach (var notification in _notifications)
                        {
                        <MudMenuItem>@notification</MudMenuItem>
                        }
                        <MudDivider/>
                        <MudMenuItem OnClick="@ClearNotifications">Clear all</MudMenuItem>
                        }
                    </ChildContent>
                </MudMenu>

                <MudMenu ActivationEvent="@MouseEvent.LeftClick" AnchorOrigin="Origin.BottomLeft" TransformOrigin="Origin.TopCenter">
                    <ActivatorContent>
                        <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Person" Color="Color.Inherit" Edge="Edge.End"/>
                    </ActivatorContent>
                    <ChildContent>
                        <MudMenuItem>
                            <form method="post" action="Account/Logout">
                                <input type="hidden" name="ReturnUrl" value="@currentUrl"/>
                                <AntiforgeryToken/>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link p-0 m-0 align-baseline">Logout</button>
                            </form>
                        </MudMenuItem>
                    </ChildContent>
                </MudMenu>
            </Authorized>
        </AuthorizeView>
    </MudAppBar>

    <MudDrawer @bind-Open="@_drawerOpen" Elevation="25" Anchor="Anchor.Left" ClipMode="DrawerClipMode.Always">
        <AuthorizeView>
        <MudDrawerHeader Class="flex">
            <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">Oscar Pty Ltd</MudText>
        </MudDrawerHeader>
        <MudDrawerContainer>
            <NavMenu/>
        </MudDrawerContainer>
        </AuthorizeView>
    </MudDrawer>
    <MudMainContent>
        <AuthorizeView>
            <Authorized>
                <div class="p-2">
                    @Body
                </div>
            </Authorized>
            <NotAuthorized>
                <div class="p-6">
                    @Body
                </div>
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeView>
    </MudMainContent>
</MudLayout>

when i inspect the logout button i can see
<form method="post" action="Account/Logout" class="mud-form gap-0"><!--!--><button type="submit" disabled="" style="display: none" aria-hidden="true"></button><!--!--><!--!--><!--!--><input type="hidden" name="ReturnUrl" value="" b-hd7hv3j7oi=""><!--!-->
                                <!--!--><!--!-->
                                <!--!--><button type="submit" class="btn btn-link p-0 m-0 align-baseline" b-hd7hv3j7oi="">Logout</button></form>

as we can see that if i use MudBlazor and click logout, i will have error
AntiforgeryValidationException: The required antiforgery request token was not provided in either form field "__RequestVerificationToken" or header value "RequestVerificationToken". when logout

BadHttpRequestException: Invalid anti-forgery token found when reading parameter "string returnUrl" from the request body as form.

Does anybody face this issue? And what is the way to fix?
Try to logout without any issue when using MudBlazor Layout
#Solution:
I had been helping myself.
Logout button in MainLayout.razor:
<MudMenuItem>
    <form method="post" action="Account/Logout">
        <input type="hidden" name="__RequestVerificationToken" value="@_antiForgeryToken" />
        <input type="hidden" name="ReturnUrl" value="@currentUrl"/>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link p-0 m-0 align-baseline">Logout</button>
    </form>
</MudMenuItem>

Code logic in MainLayout.razor
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var tokens = Antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext);
    _antiForgeryToken = tokens.RequestToken;
    currentUrl = NavigationManager.ToBaseRelativePath(NavigationManager.Uri);
    NavigationManager.LocationChanged += OnLocationChanged;

}

this will work

I just bumped into the same problem and it took me a couple of hours understanding that MudMenuItem was preventing the AntiforgeryToken to render correctly.
I could not find a clean solution, but I found an ugly hack :
Write another hidden form outside the <MudMenuItem> tag (with a different @formname, otherwise the form won't work).
Also, when doing that, I have a new problem : the submit button triggers a "Form submission canceled because the form is not connected" error.
So I replaced the submit button by a classic button and a piece of javascript to submit the form.
In my case it looks like that :
<Authorized>
<MudMenu Edge="Edge.End" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Person" Color="Color.Inherit">
    <MudMenuItem>
        <MudNavLink Href="Account/Manage" Match="NavLinkMatch.Prefix" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Person">@context.User.Identity?.Name</MudNavLink>
    </MudMenuItem>
    <MudMenuItem>
        <form action="Account/Logout" method="post" @formname="main" id="mainForm">
            <input type="hidden" name="ReturnUrl" value="@currentUrl" />

            <button type="button" class="nav-link btn btn-link" onclick="document.getElementById('mainForm').submit();">
                <span class="bi bi-arrow-bar-left-nav-menu" aria-hidden="true"></span> Logout
            </button>

            <AntiforgeryToken />
        </form>
    </MudMenuItem>
</MudMenu>
<!-- Hidden form because of a problem with MudMenuItem -->
<form action="Account/Logout" method="post" style="display:none" @formname="secondary" id="secondaryForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="ReturnUrl" value="@currentUrl" />

    <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link">
        <span class="bi bi-arrow-bar-left-nav-menu" aria-hidden="true"></span> Logout
    </button>

    <AntiforgeryToken />
</form>

A bit ugly I reckon, but it solved my problem.

Hi Christian, it seems like your solution similar to mine, you can review my solution that i have updated above. Thanks for your time.
